# Línea roja como espacio en SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

Estoy desarrollando un sistema que lee información de un Excel, y esa información la guarda en mi base de datos. Al querer hacer una consulta en mi base sobre un campo en específico, mi consulta no generaba ningún registro y noté lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> nombre  apellido

Al copiar mi celda y pegarla en el editor de SQL Server, me aparecían estas líneas rojas en lugar de los espacios, pero a la hora de hacer un `SELECT` a mi tabla esas líneas son invisibles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo hacía lo siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tabla where nombre like '% %'
```

El espacio del `LIKE` lo pongo desde mi teclado. A la hora de ejecutar no me regresaba ningún registro. Entonces decidí copiar la línea roja y ponerla dentro de mi `LIKE` y quedó de la siguiente manera visualmente:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tabla where nombre like '% %'
```

Visualmente es igual, pero la diferencia es que a la hora de ejecutar me regresa los registro que cumplen con la condición. **Este caracter tiene el valor 160.**

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe que salgan esas líneas rojas en lugar de espacios y cómo quitarlos?

De hecho para quitar esas líneas hice esto, aunque no siento que sea lo mas óptimo:

```
DECLARE @c char(1)
DECLARE @label varchar(100) 

SELECT DISTINCT @label = nombre 
FROM dbo.tabla1 
WHERE nombre = 'Ernesto  Zarate' 

SET @c = SUBSTRING(@label,8,1) 

UPDATE dbo.tabla1 
SET nombre = Replace(nombre,@c,' ')
```

Solución en C#:

```
protected string quitaCaracter(string cadena)
{
    string cadenaLimpia = cadena.Replace((char)160, (char)32);
    cadenaLimpia = cuentaCaracter(cadenaLimpia);
    return cadenaLimpia.Trim();
}

protected string cuentaCaracter(string cadena)
{
    string pattern = @"\s{1,}";
    return Regex.Replace(cadena, pattern, " ");
}
```

Comment: ¿Y las imágenes? Creo que te las olvidaste.

Comment: En ambos casos, estás pegando un espacio. ¿Podrías comprobar de estar copiando exactamente ese carácter que se ve como espacio pero no lo es? Una posibilidad es que sea un [espacio duro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espacio_duro) (caracter 160), pero imposible saber sin verlo.

Comment: Si se me olvidaron las imagenes disculpen ya las eh agregado.

Comment: si lo que sucede es que ambos parecen espacio pero no lo son por alguna razón como se ve en la imagen 1 mi varchar me lo devuelve como se ve en la imagen en lugar de poner un espacio en blanco sale con esa linea roja o guión largo como lo quieran ver esa linea roja la pego en mi like y lo tomo como espacio

Comment: Sin embargo, no es lo que pegaste en tu pregunta. ¿Podrías pegar el texto de la primera imagen en la pregunta?

Comment: nombre  apellido
Como puedes notar es un espacio, pero tengo el problema de cuando hago mis consultas sql no lo toma como un espacio normal si no hasta que pego la linea roja y la pongo en mi where ya funciona

Comment: esa "línea roja" es la que estoy intentando que pegues en tu pregunta

Comment: Yo estoy viendo esas lineas rojas, la pregunta no debio ser cerrada si no redactada de otra manera. El problema de @ErnestoZarateJurado es que tiene que actualizar la cache del IntelliSense `CTRL+SHIFT+R`

Comment: Ya la eh pegado lo que sucede es que al pegarla en otro editor es simplemente un espacio. 
En palabras mas simples, 
linea roja se ve en SQLSever
cualquier otro editor es un espacio en blanco

Comment: @Juanche ya eh actualizado mi cache y siguen saliendo

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es intentar averiguar que caracter es en realidad ese espacio usando `ASCII` . Tienes que calcular en que lugar esta el espacio y ejecutar algo como `SELECT ASCII(substring(tucolumna,posiciondelespacio,1))` Si lo consigues comenta que código te aparece

Comment: @Pikoh me ha salido el codigo ascii numero 160

Comment: Entonces mira el comentario de @mariano mas arriba para la explicacion :)

Comment: De hecho para quitar esas lineas hice esto, aunque no siento que sea lo mas optimo `DECLARE @c char(1)
 DECLARE @label varchar(100)
 SELECT DISTINCT @label = nombre FROM dbo.tabla1 WHERE nombre = 'Ernesto  Zarate'
 SET @c = SUBSTRING(@label,8,1)
 UPDATE dbo.tabla1
 SET nombre =  Replace(nombre,@c,' ')` . Aunque me quedo la duda de que por que se guarda en mi base

Comment: Solo es visual infromativo, como cuando tienes un error ortografico, pero en este caso indica error de sintaxis y esto no afecta a los datos en nada, es solo como se esta viendo, si copiase ese dato a notepad no te va aparecer la linea...

Comment: De echo me ayudo leer este blog http://jldexcelsp.blogspot.mx/2012/10/el-extrano-caso-del-espacio-inamovible.html y es lo que sucede es un caracter ascii el 160. 
Comparto mi codigo en c# que quito esos caracteres y pongo un espacio en blanco limpio por asi decirlo y en caso de tener mas de dos espacios en blanco lo convierte a uno solo

Comment: `protected string quitaCaracter(string cadena)
        {
            string cadenaLimpia = cadena.Replace((char)160, (char)32);
            cadenaLimpia = cuentaCaracter(cadenaLimpia);
            return cadenaLimpia.Trim();
        }
        protected string cuentaCaracter(string cadena)
        {
            string pattern = @"\s{1,}";
            return Regex.Replace(cadena, pattern, " ");
        }`

Comment: @ErnestoZarateJurado si lo que pusiste soluciono tu problema, seria bueno que lo pongas como respueta a la pregunta.. y dentro de unos dias podras aceptarla! queda mucho mas claro que en un comentario.

Comment: trata de no poner la respuesta en la pregunta. Las auto respuestas son bienvenidas tambien!

Comment: ¿No te soluciona el problema si `quitaCaracter` tiene simplemente `return Regex.Replace(cadena, @"\s{1,}, " ").Trim()`?